# Calculate attendance status

Tags: google-sheets

I want to be able to determine "Attendance Status" (Column B) based on if someone has attended within the last 4 (may want to change over time) weeks. So on the [attached Sample Book](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1d3yvaXqGbkheCQCdaEx0Ybqqglse1mgu3GI0Fs8EJp0/edit#gid=0), if anyone attended Aug-11 or later would have Y for "Attending".

This is a formula that works in Excel, but not in GSheets pasted in B2 and copied down:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET(INDEX($C$1:$X$1,MATCH(TODAY(),$C$1:$X$1)),ROWS(B$2:B2),-(4-1),,4),"X")>0,"Y","N")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will work.
`=IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(OFFSET($C$1,0, MATCH(TODAY(),$C$1:$X$1)-1))-3) , ":", ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(OFFSET($C$1,0, MATCH(TODAY(),$C$1:$X$1)-1))))),"X")>0,"Y","N")`